# Maintain PTS on .ts file resize

Tags: ffmpeg

Let's say I have a .ts file from an existing HLS and I simply want to resize it.  For example, to create a second lower-resolution stream that can be switched when bandwidth is poor.

```
ffmpeg -i video1080_1.ts -vf "scale=1280:720" video720_1.ts
```

How do I ensure that video720_1.ts starts at the exact same PTS as video1080_1.ts?  I haven't changed the rate, so it will play fine as long as it starts at the exact same PTS.

I have tried a lot of things (vsync, copyts, etc.) but none of them give me the exact same number.

Also, I tried adding `-copyts -vsync 2 -muxdelay 0 -muxpreload 0` and that got it closer, but still off by 1100 (4422778 vs 4423680).

Answer (score 0):

OK, after much testing, I found that the following does in fact give me the exact same PTS as the original:

```
ffmpeg -i 00091.ts -vf "scale=640:360" -copyts -vsync -1 -muxdelay 0 -muxpreload 0 -y 00091_360.ts
```

All 4 parameters are required together.

Edit: `-vsync -1` is the default and is optional.